# WebDriverBackedSelenium -getElementTagName execution failed error

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Iam Using WebDriverBackedSelenium and tyring to run my RC cases,i get following error,

**Error :**

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: getElementTagName execution failed;  Element does not exist in cache Backtrace:    0x43f80e    0x4320ae    0x4327e1    0x4336dc    0x4347ba    0x4250e9    0x42ca6c    0x41a597    0x484df8    0x4861f2    0x486491    start_thread [0x7f615369dd8c]   0x7f6150cde04d  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.6.0', revision: '13840', time: '2011-09-13 14:55:30' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-10-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_22' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver     at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.SeleneseCommand.apply(SeleneseCommand.java:42)

**Code i used :**

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

```
  Selenium selenium = null;

  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,getCurrentSetupURL());
```

selenium.type("id","value") - in this line error is thrown!

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify what ID you want to write in. Assume you try to login the user. So in most cases the login page HTML will look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="username"></input>
<input type="password" id="password"></input>
```

In order to fill these in, the commands look like this:

```
selenium.type("id=username", "username");
selenium.type("id=password", "password");
```

The above code will enter value `username` into username field and value `password` into password field

If you never specified what `id` and `value` in your code mean, then obvipously you get nullpointerException

Comment: you mean to say i should use selenium.type("id=username", "username"); instead of selenium.type("username", "<username>");

Comment: yep. Or better approach is to have selenium IDE installed in your browser and record testcase by it. Then export to your project